# Add object to Realm List just once

Tags: ios, swift, rest, realm

How do I update a `List` object without deleting all objects and appending a record with a specific primary key twice?

For example:

I have a `User` object. This user has many `locations` from type `UserLocation`. If I ask my RESTful API now for all locations (e.g. `/api/users/6/locations`) I want to check if still all locations are up to date and eventually update and delete invalidated once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UserLocation.create(..., update: true)` for updating the objects with existing primary keys, see more in [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#creating-and-updating-objects-with-primary-keys).

As for deletion you have to manually delete invalid objects, however you don't need to delete if from `Lists`, you can just delete it from realm and your relationships will be updated automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But if i `append` the user location to the `List` it still gets added twice after the next request. Is it somehow possible to append or update if already in that `List`?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do similar thing in one of my past projects. I am not sure this is the best way to do that.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
realm.beginWrite()

let locations = User.locations //existing locations

var locIdsAdded : [String] = []
//1. collect existing locations
let existingIds = channels.map({ (loc) -> String in
    return loc.primaryKey
})
//2. add or update objects from server
for loc in locationDictsFromServer {
    let locObj = parseFromDict(loc) //parse dictionary into RealmObject
    realm.add(locObj, update: true) // update: true not to add duplicated
    if(existingIds.index(of: locObj.primaryKey) == nil) { // check if need to add
        user.locations.append(locObj)
    }
    locIdsAdded.append(locObj.primaryKey)
}
//3. remove non updated objects
var removeSet:Set<String> = Set(existingIds)
removeSet.subtract(locIdsAdded)
for(removeId) in removeSet {
    if let obj2Remove = realm.object(ofType: UserLocation.self, forPrimaryKey: removeId) {
        realm.delete(obj2Remove)
    }
}
try! realm.commitWrite()
```